# Erratic mouseover behavior with nested items inside mouseover layer

Tags: javascript, mouseover, addeventlistener

So let's say we have:

- A container for everything
- A baseDiv inside that container

> ```
> //let's create a base layer
> var container = document.getElementById('container')
> var baseDiv = document.createElement('div')
> baseDiv.id = 'baseDiv'
> baseDiv.innerText = 'this is the base div'
> baseDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', createLayer)
> container.appendChild(baseDiv)
> ```

When the user mouses over:

- A layerOnTop, of the same size is put on top of the baseDiv.

When the user mouses out:

- The layerOnTop is removed.

> ```
> function createLayer(){
>     console.log('creating layer')
>     layerOnTop = document.createElement('div')
>     layerOnTop.id = 'layerOnTop'
>     layerOnTop.addEventListener('mouseout', 
>                   function(){
>                       console.log('removing layer')
>                       return layerOnTop.parentElement.removeChild(layerOnTop)
>                            })
>     container.appendChild(layerOnTop) }
> ```

Simple and works great.

- However, when layerOnTop contains elements as well (buttons, inputs), the behavior gets very erratic and starts flicking as you're technically exiting the layerOnTop.

> ```
> //it contains two textareas
> layerOnTop.appendChild(document.createElement('textarea'))
> layerOnTop.appendChild(document.createElement('textarea'))
> ```

I wish I could use mouseenter but it doesn't seem to be supported by Chrome.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DjRBP/

How can I stop this? I wish I could merge the textareas and layerOnTop into one large mouseover-handling conglomerate.

Comment: `I wish I could use mouseenter but it doesn't seem to be supported by Chrome.` - why do you say that? **EDIT**: Nevermind, it seems that jQuery normalizes mouse events (which I'm used to) so they are consistent and compatible across browsers. But the actual `mouseenter` event isn't as supported as I thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check in your mouse out event that it's actually leaving the element. Change your mouseout function to:

```
function(event) {
    var e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;
    if (e.parentNode == this || e == this) {
        // We're not actually leaving the parent node so don't remove layer
        return;
    }

    console.log('removing layer')
    return layerOnTop.parentElement.removeChild(layerOnTop)
})
```